# What were the geographical locations associated with the names of the 24 families of Kohanim after their civil war and before the Maccabees?

Tags: kohen-priest, temple-service-avoda

We know that the Kohanim were split into 24 mishmaros. Each was a distinct family, with a distinct family name and location. What were the geographical locations associated with the names of the 24 families of Kohanim when:

1. the ten tribes separated from Judea and established their capital in Samaria?  Did the 20 families of the Kohanim continue to serve in Jerusalem while residing outside of Judea or were there adjustments made as there was when only four families returned from Babylon?
2. the Second Temple was built before the Maccabees revolted?

I already have the locations of the 24 watches after the destruction of the Second Temple by the Romans.

I do thank you for allowing me to attend this website and I am trying to work within your parameters. I thank you again for your patience.

Another way of asking the same question:
Let us put aside the governmental body directing where each mishmarot were to settle.  Is it unreasonable to assume that each designated mishmarot in David’s/Solomon’s time did locate in an area that was apart from another mishmarot - even one of their own choosing or tradition.  It seems that the Hebrew philosophy was tribal in nature.  As clans they would have a cohesive nature.  Even if nomadic to any degree, they would have been in a certain, self-prescribed location.  Even if each of the four families that returned from exile stayed in one area, there should be four areas that can be located.
Should we not want to know were each mishmarot was located, first with Solomon’s Temple, and then later with the Second Temple?  Is it not disturbing that the only areas we know about is the one area that might mean the least;  after the destruction of the Second Temple?
Even then the twenty-four were separated from each other.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Do you have any reason to think that the mishmarot were centered around specific locations during this time?

Comment: When the Israelites arrived in Palestine, the land was divided between the tribes with the exception of the Levites.  The Levites were divided and lived throughout the land assigned to the different tribes.  After the Second Temple was destroyed by the Romans, each of the 24 watches were optimistically assigned a location in Galilee.  Why wouldn't the 24 watches be distributed somewhat equally throughout Palestine?  We know that each watch was composed of clans and had a very large amount of Priests and Levites in each group and they ensured that the ritual needs were met.  Richard Fraker

Comment: It sounds like you assume an orderly and formal division of the Levites and priests, as though some official governmental body directed each mishmar where to settle. But was that really the case? Or did it just happen that the mishmarot gradually came to settle around random villages and cities in the Galilee? There certainly were other places where the priests settled after the destruction, such as Gophna, which is not on the Galilean list.